# iOS: Export compliance when using CryptoSwift and SSL

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have a question. My app connects with the external server using HTTPS, it uses also CryptoSwift library to encrypt and decrypt some files stored in it using AES and SHA-1 for hash. I use also OpenSSL library to verify in-app purchase receipt. How should I answer about export compliance? If I correct understand for the question "Does your app uses encryption?" I should select Yes, but for the second question "Does your app qulify for any of the exemptions provided in Category 5, Part2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations?" should I also select Yes? Do I need then send any document to App Store Connect or to U.S. government or France government?

Thank you in advance for any help.